# Light theme action bar have weird artefact since AppCompat v21

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

Since I upgraded appcompat to v21 (now on v22.2.1), when using light theme, the action bar have a very odd artefact as seen on the screenshot below. When using dark theme, no problems whatsoever!

I tried to change the style of the action bar using this and it works, however there's no more title! All other ActionBar styles are showing the artefact.

```
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabBar</item>
```

Here are my dark/light themes definitions:

```
<style name="AT_Theme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="switchStyle">@style/switch_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/CustomTheme.ButtonTextAppearance</item>

    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/abc_btn_radio_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/abc_btn_check_material_light</item>
</style>

<style name="AT_Theme_Light" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff000000</item>

    <item name="switchStyle">@style/switch_light</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/CustomTheme.ButtonTextAppearance</item>

    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/abc_btn_radio_material</item>
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/abc_btn_check_material</item>
</style>
```

I tried tweaking/overriding a lot of things to no avail. Also search for a color definition or drawable that would do that, no result there either.

Please help me get rid of that artefact:

[image: White theme artefact]

[image: Dark theme ok]

Comment: Looks like you are using a TabBar style for the ActionBar, instead of an ActionBar style.

Comment: If I don't use a ToolBar or TabBar style (effectively using the ActionBar style) I get this weird effect, but only with light theme, that's the issue I was having, hence the solution I posted below..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was so simple:

1) Change actionBarStyle in app's custom theme, both light/dark works with this:

```
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Toolbar</item>
```

2) Enable title in code:

```
    ActionBar ab = aba.getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null)
        ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE,ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```